# javascript library for 3d transformations

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've created the sample for 3d-transformations in browser:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="cube">
        <div id="top">TOP</div>
        <div id="front">FRONT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
#cube div{ 
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50% -150px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s linear; 
    border:1px solid black;
}
#cube:hover #top{
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) translate3d(0,0,-150px) rotate3d(1,0,0,0);
}
#cube:hover #front{
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) translate3d(0,0,-150px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-90deg);
}
#cube #top{ 
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) translate3d(0,0,-150px) rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg);
}
#cube #front{ 
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) translate3d(0,0,-150px) rotate3d(1,0,0,0);
}
```

You can see this sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/basilkot/reAaJ/4/).

But for now it works for chrome only and i want to make it more crossbrowserly. Can anybody suggest some javascript-library for 3d-transformations? Is there a way to transform images and text?

Answer (score 1):

Here a plugin for css3 effects

[Effects](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)

and kindly read this as note:
  [Note(othr brwsers)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see "transit.js" you've mentioned provide 2d transformations which is not so fast as 3d (because of GPU support for translate3d(...) instead of translate(..))

[image: Proof]

Original image url - http://pix.academ.org/img/2015/05/21/64bcd912c0851604977d73c7d1f82778.png